# How can I capture a consistent snapshot of a directory and all its children?

Tags: backup, tar, ext4, snapshot

We have an application that periodically backs itself up to a directory on the local file system. Inside this directory are several more files and directories.

I want to produce a "snapshot" of all these files that can be copied to backup storage.

Most importantly, how can I produce this "snapshot" in an atomic manner? Keep in mind that all the while, any of these files may be modified by the backup daemon rendering our "snapshot" inconsistent.

Edit:

Perhaps I should mention that the system has an `ext4` file system.

Comment: You could use `devicemapper` and capture a snapshot or - and, in my opinion, easier - a `btrfs` snapshot. You might also use `mksquashfs` to create a mountable compressed mirror of the tree.

Comment: The system in question has an `ext4` filesystem. Are the tools you mentioned applicable? They all seem to apply to different filesystems.

Comment: in that case `btrfs` might not be, but the others are.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/252964/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-a-directory-on-linux-as-it-was-at-a-particular-point-i

Answer (score 3):

If you know which processes are writing to files in that directory, you can freeze them using `kill -SIGSTOP <pid>`, do your backup then resume the processes with `kill -SIGCONT <pid>`.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, atomicity of such a transaction cannot be guaranteed by ext4 in itself without cooperation from the application that is accessing the data concurrently.
Using some snapshot mechanism in an underlying device mapper won't work either, since you'd basically need to unmount the filesystem (or at least remount-ro) in order to obtain a consistent state on the block device level.

I think without additional knowledge about the behavior of the application, this is going to be pretty complicated. So the easiest way out is probably to modify the application in some way (like introducing a lockfile). If, however, you need to treat it as a black box, I'm going to make a few assumptions about it:

1. The periodic backup by the application is only taking a short amount of time compared to the interval at which it is performed
2. After finishing its backup, it will close all file handles until the next backup run

Based on these assumptions, I would suggest an optimistic approach. Simply put, just try to make a regular, recursive, non-atomic copy of the directory and check afterwards if the application has touched any of the files. If it did, this indicates that your copy unfortunately coincided with the periodic self-backup of the application. In that case, discard the copy you just created and try it all over again. Maybe back off for some time; avoid a resource-hogging infinite loop.

You can implement this by using the inotify mechanism in Linux as a means of watching the files you want to copy during the process. If you are going for a simple shell script, take a look at [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki). It's packaged on most distros.
I'm not entirely sure how inotify behaves when files are already open, so referring to assumption number 2, you probably also want to use `lsof` to make sure that your application has no open file handles on any of the contents of your source directory. Do that *after* you set up the inotify watches.

So this is how I would address your situation. I hope you don't mind if I'll skip sketching an actual implementation of this. Feel free to ask me if anything's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
/sbin/fsfreeze --freeze /data
# do a backup
/sbin/fsfreeze --unfreeze /data
```

> fsfreeze - suspend access to a filesystem (Ext3/4, ReiserFS, JFS, XFS)

If more info needed: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/fsfreeze.8.html